# Excel formula construction assistance, too many arguments

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

[image: Tax Table]

I'm trying to think of the proper formula for this Tax table. (See attached image) but i'm not too familiar with excels loopy format. Can you spot what's wrong with my code?

```
=IF(J2<10000,J2*0.05,IF(J2<30000,(J2-10000)*0.1+500),IF(J2<70000,(J2-30000)*.15+2500),IF(J2<140000,(J2-70000)*.20+8500),IF(J2<250000,(J2-140000)*.25+22500),IF(J2<500000,(J2-250000)*.30+50000),IF(J2>500000,(J2-500000)*.32+125000))
```

Clearer format:

```
IF(J2<10000,
J2*0.05,
IF(J2<30000,
(J2-10000)*0.1+500),
IF(J2<70000,
(J2-30000)*.15+2500),
IF(J2<140000,
(J2-70000)*.20+8500),
IF(J2<250000,
(J2-140000)*.25+22500),
IF(J2<500000,
(J2-250000)*.30+50000),
IF(J2>500000,
(J2-500000)*.32+125000))
```

It's saying I have entered too many arguments. There are exactly 7 IF statements. is there any way I can make this work? Hopefully without using names or variables because I actually want to transfer this formula as is into a C# program, so this format is preferred.

Comment: Note that, once you get your parentheses fixed up, your innermost `IF` statement will return `FALSE` if J2 contains the number 500000.

Comment: I know this is solved, but you could use a `VLOOKUP` with the last thing as FALSE instead. Just set the column A number to the starting one (Like 0, 10001, 30001, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes Excel's remark about "too many arguments" is to be read as "too many parentesis".

Try this version of your formula:

```
=IF(J2<10000,J2*0.05,IF J2<30000,(J2-10000)*0.1+500,IF J2<70000,(J2-30000)*.15+2500,IF J2<140000,(J2-70000)*.20+8500,IF J2<250000,(J2-140000)*.25+22500,IF J2<500000,(J2-250000)*.30+50000,IFJ2>500000,(J2-500000)*.32+125000)
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out eventually after realizing the parenthesis's did not match when separated. Guess it's not so confusing after all!

Answer (score 2):

I have no excel handy for another 2 hours to test but look at you closing of the nested if formulas. 
I have the impression  you close each before the 'else' argument. You did it the right way in the first if. Put all the closing ')'  to the end.

Answer (score 2):

The formula you are after is:

```
=IF(J2< 10000, J2        *0.05,
 IF(J2< 30000,(J2- 10000)*0.10+   500,
 IF(J2< 70000,(J2- 30000)*0.15+  2500,
 IF(J2<140000,(J2- 70000)*0.20+  8500,
 IF(J2<250000,(J2-140000)*0.25+ 22500,
 IF(J2<500000,(J2-250000)*0.30+ 50000,
              (J2-500000)*0.32+125000))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do this in VBA, it would be much more readable, maintainable, and extensible :) Here's my take on it:

```
Public Function TaxDue(TaxableIncome As Double) As Double

    Select Case TaxableIncome
        Case Is < 10000
            TaxDue = TaxableIncome * 0.05
        Case Is < 30000
            TaxDue = TaxableIncome * 0.1 + 500
        Case Is < 70000
            TaxDue = TaxableIncome * 0.15 + 2500
        Case Is < 140000
            TaxDue = TaxableIncome * 0.2 + 8500
        Case Is < 250000
            TaxDue = TaxableIncome * 0.25 + 22500
        Case Is < 500000
            TaxDue = TaxableIncome * 0.3 + 50000
        Case Else
            TaxDue = TaxableIncome * 0.32 + 125000
    End Select

End Function
```

For this to work you have to put it in a module in the file where you want to use the formula. After it's in the module, simply type =TaxDue in a cell.